Movie featuring a hurricane near land
I would like help locating an old movie (maybe black and white).  I vividly recall the last scene, but the other details are pretty hazy, other than it featured a hurricane.
In the last scene we see a man (perhaps a fugitive, who may or may not be guilty) clinging to a tree trunk at nighttime, (and making his escape?) after the hurricane.  The setting of the movie might have been an island, perhaps even a Caribbean island.
Any help would be appreciated.

It could be The Hurricane. From the wiki:

The Hurricane is a 1937 film set in the South Seas, directed by John
  Ford and produced by Samuel Goldwyn Productions, about a Polynesian
  who is unjustly imprisoned.


The ending sounds familiar:

A once-in-a-lifetime hurricane strikes the island. A few, among them
  Dr. Kersaint and his pregnant patient, weather the disaster in a
  canoe, while Terangi ties his family and Madame De Laage to a stout
  tree. The rest drown, and the island is stripped bare.
The tree floats away. Terangi later finds a war canoe in the water,
  which he uses to get his party to a small island. When they spot the
  schooner, Terangi signals it with smoke before fleeing in the canoe
  with his family. Governor De Laage embraces his wife, but then spots
  something far away through his binoculars. Madame De Laage insists it
  must be a floating log; suspecting Tarangi saved his wife, after a
  pause, he agrees with her.


You are right!  That is precisely the movie I have in mind.
